# Makefile recompiles every time

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, linker

I'm a beginner with C and have been trying to tackle a few university tasks in regards to the makefile. It's a multi-file project and the idea is to compile `nave.c` `porto.c` `meteo.c`. and `master.c`.

All but the last need to be linked with `common_ipcs` and `utils` and are separately compiled. That said this all seems to work fine and all but my issue is that if I run any of the two target (debug or release) multiple times, they keep compiling everything from scratch even though nothing had been modified.

Any ideas? Here's my makefile with the not relevant targets removed. `dbg` is also removed as it is identical to `rls`.

```
# basic rules
CC      = gcc
LDFLAGS = -lm
COMMON  = common_ipcs.c utils.c
TARGET  = master
SOURCE  = master.c nave.c porto.c meteo.c
 
# directories
DIRSRC  = source
DIRHDR  = headers
DIRDBG  = debug
DIRRLS  = release
 
# compiling flags
CFLAGS  = -std=c89
DCFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -g -O0 -pedantic -DDEBUG
RCFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DNDEBUG
 
# $< is the first prerequisite
# $@ is the target
# $^ is all the prerequisites
 
.PHONY: all prep rls dbg drun run clean
 
# build all the prerequisites for compiling the project
all: clean prep rls
 
prep:
    @mkdir -p $(DIRDBG) $(DIRRLS)
 
rls: $(addprefix $(DIRSRC)/, $(SOURCE))
    $(CC) $(RCFLAGS) $(addprefix $(DIRSRC)/, $(COMMON)) $(DIRSRC)/nave.c -o $(DIRRLS)/nave.o $(LDFLAGS)
    $(CC) $(RCFLAGS) $(addprefix $(DIRSRC)/, $(COMMON)) $(DIRSRC)/porto.c -o $(DIRRLS)/porto.o $(LDFLAGS)
    $(CC) $(RCFLAGS) $(addprefix $(DIRSRC)/, $(COMMON)) $(DIRSRC)/meteo.c -o $(DIRRLS)/meteo.o $(LDFLAGS)
    $(CC) $(RCFLAGS) $(addprefix $(DIRSRC)/, $(COMMON)) $(DIRSRC)/master.c -o $(DIRRLS)/$(TARGET) $(LDFLAGS)
```

I've been messing with this makefile for days, it has gone through an inconceivable amount of rewrites and at this point I am not even sure what to try anymore. Relevant to this iteration, I've also tried to remove `.PHONY`, without any change in the recompilation as I had been explained that `.PHONY` also forces recompilation of all files. I've looked at different similar questions posted and none really seem to be applicable to this specific makefile issue.

Comment: Your recipe for `rls` explicitly builds `nave.o`, `porto.o`, and `meteo.o`, so yes, that will happen every time the `rls` target is built.

Comment: The usual approach would be to have a separate rule or rules for building the `.o` files (including `master.o`), and another for linking them together to form the executable (with the executable's name as the actual target name).  Then make the object files prerequisites of the link rule.

Comment: General `make` advice: minimize the use of phony targets.  That is, those where the target name is not the name of a file to be built by an associated rule.  Phony targets have a place, and there are a few conventional ones, but neophytes often get themselves into trouble by thinking of target names as if they were subroutine names, and they're not really like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confused about what [a makefile rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html) is.  A rule consists of three parts: one or more *targets*, zero or more *prerequisites*, and a *recipe* of commands to run.

Make will compare timestamps of each *target* to all its listed *prerequisites*, and if any prerequisite is newer than the target, it will start a shell to run the *recipe* which is expected to bring the target up to date.

You have this rule:

```
rls: $(addprefix $(DIRSRC)/, $(SOURCE))
        $(CC) $(RCFLAGS) $(addprefix $(DIRSRC)/, $(COMMON)) $(DIRSRC)/nave.c -o $(DIRRLS)/nave.o $(LDFLAGS)
        $(CC) $(RCFLAGS) $(addprefix $(DIRSRC)/, $(COMMON)) $(DIRSRC)/porto.c -o $(DIRRLS)/porto.o $(LDFLAGS)
        $(CC) $(RCFLAGS) $(addprefix $(DIRSRC)/, $(COMMON)) $(DIRSRC)/meteo.c -o $(DIRRLS)/meteo.o $(LDFLAGS)
        $(CC) $(RCFLAGS) $(addprefix $(DIRSRC)/, $(COMMON)) $(DIRSRC)/master.c -o $(DIRRLS)/$(TARGET) $(LDFLAGS)
```

We will ignore, for the moment, the incorrect invocation of the compiler (you are building *programs* but naming them as `.o` files which is not right, or at least not a good idea).

What does this rule say?  It tells make that there is a target named `rls` and it has the prerequisites `source/master.c`, `source/nave.c`, `source/porto.c`, and `source/meteo.c`, and that if the target `rls` is out of date it should run a recipe consisting of four invocations of the compiler which will create four different programs: three named `release/nave.o`, `release/porto.o`, `release/meteo.o`, and finally one named `release/master`.

So, make dutifully checks the timestamp of a file on your disk named `rls`, which doesn't exist so it can never be considered up to date, and since it's out of date it runs the recipe which invokes all four of those compile lines.  Every time.

When you write a makefile rule you should follow these rules: (a) each recipe should build *EXACTLY ONE* target, never more than one; and (b) the target name of the rule must be the exact name of the file that the recipe creates: if the recipe creates a file named `blahblah.o`, then the target of the rule must be `blahblah.o`.  If the recipe creates a file named `some/other/dir/foo` then the target of the rule must be `some/other/dir/foo`.

When you get better at makefiles you'll realize that there are times when it's useful and a good idea to violate these rules.  But these are a good starting point.

Comment: The rule (b) above is best accomplished by having your recipe create the file `$@` which is a variable make will set to the name it expects your recipe to create.  So if you use `$(CC) ... -o $@` for example then you know your recipe will always create the file make thought it would.

Comment: Hey, fantastic answer. Thank you very much! So, would it be correct to assume I need to make 8 targets, 4 for debug and 4 for the release configurations? Or am I able to use a more sophisticated way of doing this?

I wish I could upvote your answer, but I can't do that yet. I'll mark it as the accepted answer as soon as I put these suggestions into practice in a minute.

Comment: Creating different targets is one way to do it.  It is certainly simple to understand so maybe it's good to start.  Another way is to use _pattern rules_ which define a single template that make can use to build all the targets that match that template, so you don't have to write them all out individually.  So a pattern would be something like: `$(DIRDBG)/%.o : $(DIRSRC)/%.c` then a recipe that builds that target `$@` as a debug object.  Then another pattern rule for `$(DIRRLS)/%.o : $(DIRSRC)/%.c`

Comment: I’ve managed to build a solution that uses the pattern rules successfully and only compiles when changes are made. I’ll read up more about `.PHONY` to see why it being there or not doesn’t affect the functionality. I thought it would matter if files are the same name as targets. Does this exclude directories?

Comment: Declaring a target to be `.PHONY` means that regardless of whether the file exists or how new, or not new, its prerequisites are, make will _always_ rebuild it (will always run its recipe).  This seems the exact opposite of what you wanted so I'm not sure why you're considering it.

Comment: I don't understand the question "Does this exclude directories".  Make makes no distinction between files and directories: if you use a directory as a target then its recipe will be run if it doesn't exist, or if its prerequisites are newer than it.  Generally you **do not** want to use directories as targets or prerequisites because the rules for when the modification times of directories are updated can make the behavior unexpected.

Comment: All right, I misunderstood the functionality of .PHONY and after going through the GNU page on it again, I see where the misunderstanding was. Thank you.